# PHP - Imagick fatal error, no explanation

Tags: php

So, I am trying to convert a pdf file into a jpeg file, but when i read the pdf file with readImage($_FILES["fileinput"]["tmp_name"]) the fatal error is given. I get the file via html from which you can see below.

HTML FORM:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="generalForm" action="../includes/connect.php" method="POST">
            <label class="headLabel">DODAJ</label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input class="inputTextSub" id="naziv" name="naziv" type="text">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input class="inputTextSub" id="opis" name="opis" type="text">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input class="inputTextSub" id="datumz" name="datumz" type="date">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="inputfile" id="file" class="inputfile" />
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input class="button" style="margin-top:2em;" name="save" type="submit" value=" shrani ">
        </form>
```

and then here is the code in php that i execute when user presses the button.

```
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    if(!$_POST['naziv']==""&&!$_POST['opis']==""&&!$_POST['datumz']==""
    &&!$_POST['datumk']==""&&isset($_POST['pr'])
    &&isset($_POST['format'])&&$_FILES['inputfile']['size']>0){
        $naziv = $_POST['naziv'];
        $opis = $_POST['opis'];
        $datumz = $_POST['datumz'];
        $datumk = $_POST['datumk'];
        $pr = $_POST['pr'];
        $format = $_POST['format'];
        $modId = $_SESSION['mod_id'];
        $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name']);


                 $im = new Imagick();
/*THIS LINE*/    $im->readImage($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'].'[0]');
                 $im->writeImage("lala.jpg");
```

and finnaly, the devil himself:

> Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\includes\connect.php on line 49

Please help, im dying with this.

Comment: Remove `.'[0]'` from `$im->readImage($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'].'[0]');`

Comment: I dont understand why are you using`$_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'].'[0]'` instead `$_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'][0]` ?

Comment: if i do it as @ManpreetSingh says, the error is now:
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob `C': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\includes\connect.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\includes\connect.php(49): Imagick->readimage('C') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\includes\connect.php on line 49

Comment: if i do it like @B.Desai says, the error is the same as in the origin in the answer

Comment: @GašperBožič did you try to debug it if [0] element exists or not ?

Comment: @ManpreetSingh yes it is correct otherwise it wouldnt even enter the file. The file name is correct i am sure of it.

Comment: @ManpreetSingh how do i do that? i mean the [0] should represent the first page in the pdf file right?

Comment: the correct syntax in imagick is: readImage("filepath.pdf[pagenumber]")

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/imagick.readimage.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151422/discussion-between-manpreet-singh-and-gasper-bozic).

Answer (score -1):

It look like as you are using bad syntax.

`$_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'].'[0]'`

I think you wanted to do something like this `$_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'][0]`

If still it gives you error, try to debug it like this :

```
//$im = new Imagick();
//$im->readImage($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'].'[0]');
//$im->writeImage("lala.jpg");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name']);
```

and check if element `[0]` exists or not.

If `[0]` element exists than replace this line `$_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'][0]` with `$im->readImage($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'].'[0]');`

If `[0]` element doesn't exists than use `$im->readImage($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'];`